# Steps to upgrade existing Android database w/o losing data

Tags: android, database

I have an app that is being used by beta testers. My original schema did not end up working for my actual implementation of the feature I'm currently working on. I want to update the database. I do not want my testers to lose their data.

My understanding is that the steps for this are:

**1) Leave my SQLiteOpenHelper class's onCreate method AS IS**. I leave it as it is currently / originally written, the "version one" schema as I think of it.

UPDATE 2015-04-19: Step One is WRONG. See my own (accepted) answer below for details.

**2) Fill in my SQLiteOpenHelper class's onUpgrade method.** Here I make all the changes to go from the first schema to the second. (and in the future maybe write the changes needed to go from the second schema to a third)

**3) Update the database version.** In my app, I keep this as a static var. When I'm ready to pull the trigger and update the database, I change this var (DB_VERSION) from 1 to 2. This var being 2 versus the app installed on the device having a version of 1 is what triggers onUpgrade() to be called the first time the database is opened (in my case, the app's onCreate).

```
public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
```

...

```
class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DBHelper() {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }
```

**4) Run my app and cross my fingers.** If I get an error / made a typo in my SQL, I uninstall and run again.

**Can anyone verify if that is correct? Or if I'm overlooking something?**

The tutorials I've found -- when they don't just drop and recreate the database, changing the onCreate to the new schema -- don't really discuss when you already have an app and need to make a change. I guess it's not relevant to a beginner, and assumed knowledge for a non-beginner? For upgrades with user data that can't be thrown away, I only have been able to find specific question/answers about a single aspect of the upgrade, not a comprehensive guide. I'm afraid I could be missing something that's so basic/important that it "goes without saying", hence my apprehension/fear to just do it. I've searched as best as I am able, could really use some guidance! Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: keep in mind, that you'll need handle all possible upgrades each time, for example, current db version is 7, so you need to be able to upgrade from 1,2,3,4,5, and 6.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Sorry self-from-3-months-ago, turns out that's WRONG!

The problem is in step one. The onCreate is NOT left as is. It needs to create the newest version of the database. onUpdate is only called when an EXISTING user updates to the newest app release. Anyone doing a CLEAN INSTALL would end up with the old scheme, never calling onUpdate.

Here is the skeleton of my new code, which seems to handle both clean installs and upgrades. (At least I hope it does.)

```
class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DBHelper() {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        Log.i(TAG, "DBHelper called with DB_NAME " + DB_NAME + " and DB_VERSION " + Integer.toString(DB_VERSION));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        setupV1(db);
        upgradeV2(db);
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(
            final SQLiteDatabase db, final int oldVersion,
            final int newVersion)
        {
            int upgradeTo = oldVersion + 1;
            Log.i(TAG, "Upgrading database to version " + Integer.toString(upgradeTo));
            while (upgradeTo <= newVersion)
            {
                switch (upgradeTo)
                {
                    // Database v2. Added X Functionality
                    case 2:
                        upgradeV2(db);
                        break;
                    // Database v3 (not created yet)
//                      case 3:
//                          // something here
//                          break;
                }
                upgradeTo++;
            }
        }

    private void setupV1(final SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // CODE HERE TO CREATE VERSION / SCHEMA ONE OF MY DATABASE
    }

    private void upgradeV2(final SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // CODE HERE TO UPDATE FROM VERSION ONE TO VERSION TWO
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is correct. You are increasing version and updating db.

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if(oldVersion < 2) {
        db.execSQL("blablabla");
    }
    if(oldVersion < 3) {
        db.execSQL("new blablabla");
    }
    if(oldVersion < 4) {
        db.execSQL("newest blablabla");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   > Can anyone verify if that is correct?
```

**Yes**

Thats the way it worked for my android apps. My code looks like this:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION_3_MYTABLE_WITH_NOTES = 3;
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION_4_CATEGORY_ACTIVE = 4;
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION_5_REPORT_VIEW = 5;

    // points to latest version
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_VERSION_5_REPORT_VIEW;

    public DatabaseHelper(final Context context, final String databaseName) {
        super(context, databaseName, null, DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_VERSION);
        ....
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(final SQLiteDatabase db, final int oldVersion,
                          final int newVersion) {
        Log.w(this.getClass().toString(), "Upgrading database from version "
                + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion + ". (Old data is kept.)");
        if (oldVersion < DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_VERSION_3_MYTABLE_WITH_NOTES) {
            this.version3Upgrade_MYTABLE_WITH_NOTES(db);
        }
        if (oldVersion < DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_VERSION_4_CATEGORY_ACTIVE) {
            this.version4Upgrade_CATEGORY_ACTIVE(db);
        }
        if (oldVersion < DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_VERSION_5_REPORT_VIEW) {
            this.version5Upgrade_REPORT_VIEW(db);
        }
    }

    private void version3Upgrade_MYTABLE_WITH_NOTES(final SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // added MYTABLE.notes
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + MyTable.TABLE
                + " ADD COLUMN " + MyTable.COL_NOTES + " TEXT");
    }
```

I have one const and one method to upgrade from one version to the next.

Comment: Thanks! With both the first answer and yours being very similar, I accepted the first. I still really appreciate having a second voice confirm what I thought!